# How to add more data in java bson document with looping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i want to looping the code, every loop the data saved to document variable, how to add more data to document, i have problem when the loop more than 1 loop. can you give me an idea how to do it? thank you anyway

```
private Document getProcessInstances(String status, int page, int size, String sort){
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();


            Document processinstancelist = null;

            Integer totalItems = this.getTotalItems(status, page, size, sort);
            Integer totalPages = totalItems/size;


            try{


                while (page<=totalPages){

                url.append(activitiqueryhost).append("/v1/process-instances?status=").append(status).append("&page=").append(page).append("&size=").append(size).append("&sort=").append(sort);
                // System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>> URL="+url.toString());

                ResponseEntity<String> processinstancestring = this.get(url.toString()); 
                // System.out.println("processinstancestring="+processinstancestring.getBody());

                Document processinstance = Document.parse(processinstancestring.getBody());
                // System.out.println(">>>>> processinstance=" + processinstance.toJson());

                // Document
                processinstancelist = (Document) processinstance.get("list");
                // System.out.println(">>>>> list=" + processinstancelist.toJson());
                System.out.println("==== datanya "+totalItems);
                System.out.println("==== total page "+totalPages);
                System.out.println("==== datanya "+page);


                page++;

                }



                return processinstancelist;
            }
            catch(Exception  e){
                return null;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your code

Comment: @JohnMathew on code, i want to get all data from API, and the API using pagination... so i iterate the pagination by URL, and then i want to save all data in processinstancelist variable...

Comment: in your code the variable value replacing in every iteration, you have to to add with existing data. eg sum=0;sum=sum+i;

Comment: @JohnMathew i have do it , but not working